# H2O Multi-core Initialization on Docker

Tags: python, docker, h2o

I'm trying to launch H2O 3.26.0.3 through Python 3.6.8 using the command:

> h2o.init(nthreads=-1)

On a 16-core virtual machine, H2O correctly initializes with this setting:

```
H2O cluster total cores:    16
H2O cluster allowed cores:  16
```

But on a 16-core Docker container, H2O initializes with this unusual setting:

```
H2O cluster total cores:    1
H2O cluster allowed cores:  1
```

Is there a reason why H2O doesn't recognize all the CPU cores in a container setting?

**Edit**
If I modify the initialization to explicitly list all cores:

> h2o.init(nthreads=16)

Then the settings look like this:

```
H2O cluster total cores:    1
H2O cluster allowed cores:  16
```

It seems odd that the allowed cores can exceed the total cores. But after some testing, H2O does appear to use multiple cores instead of a single core. So even if H2O doesn't detect multiple cores, it can still make use of them.

Comment: try to start your container with `--cpus=16`

Comment: Look at this line of code, which is what calculates it:  https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/438f67ff3f37a6a5995f6de2c1ff052464127744/h2o-core/src/main/java/water/util/LinuxProcFileReader.java#L361

Comment: LinPy - The container is running on 16 cores. In my updated description, I tested and verified that multiple cores are used by H2O. So the problem is not the container being configured incorrectly. It appears to be a quirk in H2O.